# Transform static vars to `process.env` properties with Babel

Tags: babeljs

[babel-plugin-dev-expression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dev-expression) can be used to transform `__DEV__` to `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`.

But is there a Babel transform plugin to convert other "code fence" symbols to `process.env` expressions?

For example, I'd like to be able to transform `__DEBUG__` to `process.env.DEBUG`.

Before I try to write a plugin myself, does anyone know of one that already exists? Google is not turning up anything, but I'm sure it must exist as I won't be the first person who's wanted this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that does this: [babel-plugin-transform-replace-expressions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-replace-expressions)

Initially I'd thought it was just doing a string-based search and replace, but actually it's more sophisticated than that, so it fulfils the use case.